# .Net Core 3.1 Migrations. IdentityDbContext does not inherit DbContext

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using MySql and trying to add asp.net Identities to it via migrations.

I have ApplicationDbContext class:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);            
    }
}
```

Also I already have all migrations and configurations. So this project works well on another machine.

But when I'm trying to run command `Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName Web.Data.ApplicationDbContext` I'm getting an error `"The type 'ApplicationDbContext' does not inherit from DbContext. The DbMigrationsConfiguration.ContextType property must be set to a type that inherits from DbContext."`

How could I fix it?

Comment: You are mixing EF6 and EF Core commands. There is no "Enable-Migrations" command for EF Core. And of course `DbContext` class in EFC is different form EF6 class with the same name. Hence the message (the EF6 command is expecting your class to inherit `DbContext` from EF6).

Comment: @IvanStoev But how could I run a migration than?

Comment: `Add-Migration ...`, then `Update-Database` etc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell

Comment: @IvanStoev I already have a migration, but runing Update-Database throws an error "No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'Web'."

Comment: Then you probably don't have EF Core tools installed. Did you [Verify the installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#verify-the-installation)? Or I don't know - how did you create the migration? Should be with `Add-Migration` command, then `Update-Database` should work as well. I guess you are not trying to use migrations generated by EF6 - they are not compatible with EFC, neither the migration history table.

Comment: @IvanStoev It was so dumb, Thanks a lot, that was the problem!